# Неясности с деревом процессов

Tags: unix

Я запускаю терминал. В нем запускаю firefox. Если я закрою терминал, тоесть убью процесс, который является родительским к процессу, в котором работает firefox, то firefox тоже завершится. Почему это так? Разве родитель firefox не должен поменяться на init??? Ну и соответственно firefox будет работать дальше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кратко, то при закрытии управляющего терминала контролирующий его процесс, обычно это оболочка (bash например) получает сигнал `SIGHUP` и завршает свою работу. Момимо прочего оболочка пересылает этот сигнал всем запущенным в ней задачам (jobs), что и вызывает завершение `firefox`'а.

Чтобы избежать завершения подобным образом процесс может перехватывать и обрабатывать сигнал самостоятельно; или можно предотвратить посылку сигнала детям оболочки одним из двух способов:

1. Запустить комманду с помощью `nohup`

   ```
   nohup firefox
   ```
2. Для bash можно исключить процесс из рассылки SIGHUP'а с помощью `disown`:

   ```
   firefox &
   disown $! #или disown <firefox_pid>
   ```